# How to restrict numbers (even in String type) from MaterialUI TextField?

Tags: reactjs, web, material-ui

Consider the following code:

```
<Grid item lg={6} md={6} xs={12} >
     <TextField fullWidth type={'text'} label="Product Color" value={productColor} onChange={(e) => setProductColor(e.target.value)} />
</Grid>
```

Even if it is set to type text, how do I completely prevent numbers from being entered and only allow text from A-z or a-z? Any Ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use regex like so:

```js
import { Stack, TextField } from "@mui/material";
import { useState } from "react";

const isLetters = (str) => /^[A-Za-z]*$/.test(str);

export default function IndexPage() {
  const [val, setVal] = useState("");

  const onInputChange = (e) => {
    const { value } = e.target;
    if (isLetters(value)) {
      setVal(value);
    }
  };

  return (
    <Stack spacing={2} padding={2} height={"100vh"}>
      <TextField label="Letters only" value={val} onChange={onInputChange} />
    </Stack>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of re-inventing the wheel you could use something like `react-number-format`.
They have an [example in their docs](https://github.com/s-yadav/react-number-format#custom-inputs):

```
<NumberFormat customInput={TextField} format="#### #### #### ####" />
```

It is also possible to do it the other way around, giving more control over the `TextField` but needs a bit more work.

```
import React from "react";

import { InputBaseComponentProps } from "@mui/material";
import NumberFormat from "react-number-format";

export const NumberInput = React.forwardRef<
    NumberFormat,
    InputBaseComponentProps
>((props, ref) => {
    const { onChange, ...other } = props;
    return (
        <NumberFormat
            isNumericString
            {...(other as any)}
            getInputRef={ref}
            onValueChange={(values) =>
                onChange && onChange({ target: { value: values.value } } as any)
            }
        />
    );
});
```

Then use it like this, note that the `price` value is still a string.

```
const [price, setPrice] = useState("0");

return <TextField
 value={price}
 onChange={(evt) => setPrice(evt.target.value) }
 InputProps={{
  inputComponent: NumberInput,
  inputProps: {
    decimalSeparator: ",",
    decimalScale: 2,
    fixedDecimalScale: true,
    allowNegative: false,
    prefix: "€ ",
  },
}}
```

This gives you something like this:
[image: Preview of a TextField input only accepting prices with 2 digits behind the comma]

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to to utilise the fact that you can pass in certain props to text fields and combine this with regex. This wouldn't necessarily prevent them from allowing it to be entered, however, it will prevent submission of the text field if it contains any numbers. You would then just need to add error handling to display the associated message

```
<TextField
  inputProps={{ pattern: "([^0-9]*)" }} error={'Error Message'}
/>
```

Check out the textfield api [here](https://mui.com/api/text-field/) for further details